# Are Bohm's later books worth reading?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

I mostly see Bohm's later books such as *Wholeness and the implicate order* and *The Undivided Universe* quoted in discussions of pseudoscience and quantum mysticism. Do they offer any useful insight into Quantum Mechanics or its interpretations?

Also, I have been looking for books that go into more detail on measurement and interpretations of Quantum Mechanics. I am currently reading Asher Peres' *Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods*  and Bohm's *Quantum Theory*.

Comment: "Is it worth reading _____" questions are usually fairly opinion-based

Comment: The second part would be fine on its own (though it may be a duplicate), but the first is opinion based.

Comment: I suspect that you wouldn't enjoy *Wholeness and the Implicate Order*. There's not a lot of solid physics in it. He has some interesting ideas (but he waffles on a fair bit), but it's more of a philosophy book for an educated general audience than a physics book. IMHO. I had mixed feelings about it when I read it, many years ago (before quantum mysticism had made much of an impact). I don't think I actually finished reading it...